# What is the subcategorizarion of the verb "thought"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm writing a grammar and I see that VP->thought SBAR.
The sentence "the president thought that a sandwich sighed ."
In the stanford parser.
But what is this type of verbs?

Transitive/Intransitive/Ditransitive/Complement/Other?
Thanks!

Comment: "Thought" does not have an object and hence is intransitive here.